# How can convert arrays to smaller pieces in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I have big data in the form of `object` from `mongoDB`, when i convert that to `Array` in `PHP` get this error

[Error Scrrenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6D7pA.png)

> Allowed memory size of 134217728

I think make the array smaller. what is your opinion?

Comment: you could filter the query to get what you just need so that it will not return large amount of array

Comment: If you really need all of these datas, you could use `offset` in your query to do more requests with less results.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP configuration is set to maximum `134217728 bytes`. you need to allow to maximum amount of memory that your script is currently consuming.

[memory_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) This sets the maximum amount of memory in bytes that a script is allowed to allocate. This helps prevent poorly written scripts for eating up all available memory on a server. Note that to have no memory limit, set this directive to -1.

Edit the memory_limit parameter in the php.ini file

```
memory_limit = 150M ; //that means maximum amount of memory a script may consume (150MB)
```

or if do not want to change the php.ini setting

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '150M'); // add this code in you script at the top
```

Here `150M` is example. you may give the value as you want.